# How to use $group in innner array using mongoose aggregate queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
    [

    {
        "Name":"AAA",
        "OppTag":[
            {
                "TagValue":"2016Known",
                "TagID":19
            },
            {
                "TagValue":"QQ",
                "TagID":22
            },
            {
                "TagValue":"WWW",
                "TagID":21
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name":"BBB",
        "OppTag":[
            {
                "TagValue":"WWW",
                "TagID":21
            },
            {
                "TagValue":"QQ",
                "TagID":22
            }
        ]
    }

]
```

the above response how to group by tagname using aggregate queries. the tag name present in the inner array. how to using $group inner array...pls give some solution.

Comment: How do you need the output to be?

Comment: "Tag":[
    {
        "TagValue":2016Known,
        "count":1
    },
 {
        "TagValue":QQ,
        "count":2
    },
 {
        "TagValue":WWW,
        "count":2
    }
]     
I need the below response format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the collection name is tag you should perform an aggregate query of the following form

```
db.tag.aggregate([
  {$unwind: '$OppTag'},
  {$group: { _id: '$OppTag.TagValue', count: {$sum: 1}}},
  {$project: {'_id':0, TagValue: '$_id',count: '$count'}}
])
```

When you apply the above query, you will get a response as shown below:

```
{ "count" : 2, "TagValue" : "WWW" }
{ "count" : 2, "TagValue" : "QQ" }
{ "count" : 1, "TagValue" : "2016Known" }
```